# Regular Expression restrict to enter comma and @

Tags: regex

I want reg to restrict user for `,` and `@`

I tried `[^,@]`, its not working.

Comment: did you try `[^,@]+` to get more than one?

Comment: hey its working, what was the issue. I tried `[^,@]+`

Comment: got it, what I was doing, my expression will look only for single character but if we add `+` at the end it will search for full string. am I right?

Comment: With your original code you were just checking if one character was not , or @. With the plus, the expression keeps checking until it reaches the end or something that it cannot match (ie a , or a @). EDIT: Yes, thats exactly right!

Comment: just post your comment as answer, so I could mark it as ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `[^,@]+` instead of `[^,@]` because the `+` will allow the regex to search the entire string rather than just the first value.

Comment: but in this case + will also work as I am not allowing some character and if its an empty string then also `[^,@]+` will work no need to do `[^,@]*`

Comment: Actually you are right. And in your case the `*` will not work. Edited the answer to remove that.